# Regex to replace space with char

Tags: .net

Input : `Test 1  |  Test 2   |   Test 3   |   Test 4`
Here the char `|` is like a delimiter.

can somebody give me Regular Expression or any simple way to get the string like this.
And that should not affect the space between `Test` and `3`.

The output should be `Test 1|Test 2|Test 3|Test 4`

there is not just one space. the spaces may be more than one.

Comment: You can replace `@" +\\| +"` --> `@"|"`

Answer (score 0):

This could be used as RegularExpression to match more than one space before and after the pipe

```
string pattern = @"\s+\u007C\s+";
string search = "Test 1 | Test 2 | Test 3 | Test 4";
string result = Regex.Replace(search, pattern, "|");
```

`\s+` to match one or more whitespaces
`\u007C` to match the vertical pipe `|` - The pipe is a reserved char for regex expression, so you have to use the unicode convention or escape the pipe with `\` and thus the pattern will be

```
string pattern = @"\s+\|\s+";
```

also, if you want to account for a mixed case where you have a pipe without space before or after you could change the pattern to:

```
string pattern = @"\s*\|\s*";
```

`\s*` meaning zero or more whitespaces

Comment: Steve, escaping the pipe with a backslash should work, e.g. @"\s+\|\s+". Its curious if you say its not.

Comment: @SteveSolomon, yeah, my fault. I was using a bad pattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
string text = "Test 1 | Test 2 | Test 3 | Test 4";

text = text.Replace(" | ", "|").Replace(" |", "|").Replace("| ", "|");
```

Comment: there is not just one space. the spaces may be more than one. like 'Test 1      |       Test 2       |       Test 3       |'. what to do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

A non regex way would be:

```
var tokens = input.Split('|');
foreach (var token in tokens)
{
    token.Trim();
}
string output = string.Join("|", tokens);
```

This splits the string on the delimiter, trims the individual tokens to remove the leading and trailing whitespace and then rejoins the tokens using the delimiter.